# Admin register CustomUser model gives error in Django

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm trying to register my CustomUser model that I've created and it gives me this error but I verified the files for many times and I don't understand why I'm getting this error

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'Mobile Phone',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'mobile_phone',
                )
            },
            'Email Status',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'do_not_marketing_email',
                    'email_verified',
                )
            }
        )
    )
```

error:
<class 'users.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E009) The value of 'fieldsets[4]' must be of length 2.

Comment: Add a comma after this  'mobile_phone'`,`. Django expects a tuple here.

Comment: I have now, I saw aftter that needs to be a tuple but it's still don't working

Comment: Update the question please.

Comment: Now it's updated, the same error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is expecting tuples with two elements.

```
fieldsets = (
    *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
    ('Mobile Phone', {'fields': ('mobile_phone',)}),
    ('Email Status', {'fields': ('do_not_marketing_email','email_verified')}),
)
```